# Curl API Request with PHP - long pretransfer_time

Tags: php, curl

When i make a curl api request with php, but the response returns a timeout.I tried to run curl_getinfo($ch).Found that pretransfer_time took nearly 2s.Please tell me why,thanks.

```
{
"error": "Operation timed out after 2000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received",
"info": {
    "url": "https://card.com/v1/giftcard/code",
    "content_type": null,
    "http_code": 0,
    "header_size": 0,
    "request_size": 329,
    "filetime": -1,
    "ssl_verify_result": 0,
    "redirect_count": 0,
    "total_time": 1.99945,
    "namelookup_time": 0.012225,
    "connect_time": 0.012532,
    "pretransfer_time": 1.967348,
    "size_upload": 185,
    "size_download": 0,
    "speed_download": 0,
    "speed_upload": 92,
    "download_content_length": -1,
    "upload_content_length": 185,
    "starttransfer_time": 0,
    "redirect_time": 0,
    "redirect_url": "",
    "primary_ip": "120.55.16.0",
    "certinfo": [],
    "primary_port": 443,
    "local_ip": "101.37.205.65",
    "local_port": 57156
}}
```

Comment: The used url seems to be dead